# Show nested data from JSON in table angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, html-table

I am trying to show nested data from JSON in a table but not getting succeeded.

My **json** data:-

```
$scope.data = [
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Folder": [
        {
            "Name": "Windows-Desktop",
            "CPU": "2",
            "RAM": 2,
            "FolderName": "Folder-28"
        },
         {
            "Name": "Desktop",
            "CPU": "1",
            "RAM": 1,
            "FolderName": "Folder-11"
        }
        ]
}
]
```

I tried this in **controller**:-

```
$scope.Folder = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.data.Folder, function(choose) {
      $scope.Folder.push(choose);
 }
```

In **view** I did this

```
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="sorting_1" ng-repeat="g in Folder">{{g.Name}}</td>
        <td>
            <div ng-repeat="g in Folder">
            <input class="form-control" type="text">{{g.CPU}}</input>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div ng-repeat="g in Folder">
            <input class="form-control" type="text">{{g.RAM}}</input>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am not getting any output in this. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: First mistake is that input elemet is selfclosed tag.
you have to use value attribute not inner content
like this: <input ng-value="expression"></input>. you should use ng-repeat on <tr> element.. $scope.data is an array and the field Forlder is an array to, so you ha ve to iterete twice.

Comment: @raffaeleambrosio correct. Working now thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing `$scope.data.Folder` which is not correct because `$scope.data` is an Array.

First try to loop on `$scope.data` and then a loop on `Folder`

```
$scope.Folder = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(choose) {
     if(choose && choose.Folder && choose.Folder.length) {
       angular.forEach(choose.Folder, function(choose1) {
         $scope.Folder.push(choose1);
        }
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller do like this:

```
$scope.Folder = [];
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(choose) {
   if(choose && choose.Folder){
       $scope.Folder.push(choose.Folder);
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$scope.data[0].Folder` in your controller as `$scope.data` is a array type. And I am not sure how you are rendering your table but as the question is only related to getting the value in `$scope.Folder` this is your solution.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
      {
        "$id": "1",
        "Folder": [
          {
              "Name": "Windows-Desktop",
              "CPU": "2",
              "RAM": 2,
              "FolderName": "Folder-28"
          },
           {
              "Name": "Desktop",
              "CPU": "1",
              "RAM": 1,
              "FolderName": "Folder-11"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    $scope.Folder = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.data[0].Folder, function(choose) {
      $scope.Folder.push(choose);
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="sorting_1" ng-repeat="g in Folder">{{g.Name}}</td>
        <td>
            <div ng-repeat="g in Folder">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />{{g.CPU}}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div ng-repeat="g in Folder">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />{{g.RAM}}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</div>
```

Here is one more example that I think is something you are expecting

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
      {
        "$id": "1",
        "Folder": [
          {
              "Name": "Windows-Desktop",
              "CPU": "2",
              "RAM": 2,
              "FolderName": "Folder-28"
          },
           {
              "Name": "Desktop",
              "CPU": "1",
              "RAM": 1,
              "FolderName": "Folder-11"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    $scope.Folder = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.data[0].Folder, function(choose) {
      $scope.Folder.push(choose);
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table border='1'>
   <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>CPU</th>
    <th>RAM</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat = "g in Folder">
    <td>{{g['Name']}}</td>
    <td>{{g['CPU']}}</td>
    <td>{{g['RAM']}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
  <div ng-repeat="g in item.Folder">
    Name:{{g.Name}}-
    Cpu:{{g.CPU}}-
    Ram:{{g.RAM}}
  </div>
</div>
```

using above method would eliminate the need of preparing data in your controller

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/KPBeuQmVm4xa231bssKg?p=preview)

**[Table Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xBkPxd2xniqJvtlly6BX?p=preview)**

Comment: How can you show this on my table . I tried to put `<div>` inside `<td>` didn't worked.

Comment: added demo for table

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is update your iterator function 
from
 `angular.forEach($scope.data.Folder, function(choose)`
to 
 `angular.forEach($scope.data[0].Folder, function(choose)`

look at your json Folder is first element....

Comment: Did , no change.